# C++ STL List Iterator

Tags: c++, list, stl, compiler-errors, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through a string list with the following code:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

list<string> dict = {"aardvark", "ambulance", "canticle", "consumerism"};
list<string> bWords = {"bathos", "balderdash"};
//splice the bWords list into the appropriate spot in dict
auto iterLastB = --(bWords.end());
//find spot in dict
list<string>::iterator it = dict.begin();
while(it != dict.end()){
  if(*it > *iterLastB)
    break;
    ++it;
}
dict.splice(it, bWords);
```

However, upon building this, I get the error `expected unqualified-id before 'while'`
What does this mean and how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 8):

You can't write code directly like that. At the very least you need a `main` function. You should probably add everything (except the includes) in a `main` function.

Comment: I find it strange how the OP can write code like above and forget `main`.

Comment: @JesseGood Yeah, I noticed. It looks like idiomatic C++.

Comment: I've seen students get into the habit of doing that if they use `cint` too much, but they mostly don't write good idiomatic c++.

Comment: @dmckee First time I hear about cint. Pure awesomeness :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `int main()` function. C++ simply does not allow placing code other than static variables and declarations outside of a function, as it would be unclear when the code should actually run.

A few notes: Don't use `--(container.end())`, this can end up as undefined behavior when `end` is a primitive type. Use `std::prev(container.end())`. Try to use the `begin` and `end` free functions as well, e.g. `end(container)`. Don't iterate with `while` loops, when unnecessary. Use `for(auto& x : container)` or `for(auto it = begin(container); it != end(container); ++it)`. Better yet: Use algorithms from the header `algorithm`.